# Haskell recursive sort function

Tags: sorting, haskell

I would like to implement a sort function in Haskell with these two functions:

```
smallest :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
smallest [] = error "empty list"
smallest [x] = x
smallest (x:xs)
  | x < smallest xs = x
  | otherwise = smallest xs

insert :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
insert x [] = [x]
insert x (y:ys)
  | x <= y = x:y:ys
  | otherwise = y:insert x ys
```

My idea is to insert the smallest value at the right position with a recursion but as I am new to Haskell I got some problems on how to implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
smallest (x:xs)
  | x < smallest xs = x
  | otherwise = smallest xs
```

duplicates the number of `smallest` queries at each point in the list, blowing up exponentially. Instead:

```
smallest (x:xs) = min x (smallest xs)
```

, or even just `smallest` = `minimum`. Here are a few sorts I can see with your functions or similar ones:

```
insertionSort [] = []
insertionSort (x:xs) = insert x (insertionSort xs)
```

This one will need `smallest` to give back the remaining list as well:

```
selectSmallest :: [Int] -> (Int, [Int])
selectSmallest (x:xs) = let (y, ys) = smallest xs in if x < y
  then (x, xs)
  else (y, x:ys)

selectionSorta [] = []
selectionSorta xs = let (y, ys) = smallest xs in
  y : selectionSorta ys
```